# Period of product of two complex exponential functions

Tags: exponential-function, signal-processing, periodic-functions

I have read that that period of sum/product of two periodic functions is the least common multiple of there individual time periods if the time periods are rationally related but I am not able to understand that for an exponential.

Example : Suppose $6T$ is the period of $e^{it}$ and $f(t) = e^{2it}$ and $g(t) = e^{3it}$ then

$h(t) = f(t)g(t) = e^{5it}$ whose period should be $\large\frac{6T}{5}$ but LCM gives period to be $6T.$
Any clarification?
P.S. : I am studying periodic time signals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ and $g$ have rationally related periods $p_f$ and $p_g$ then the functions $f+g$ or $f\cdot g$ are guaranteed to be periodic with period $\ell:={\rm lcm}(p_f,p_g)$, but the *fundamental period* of such compositions could as well be ${\ell\over n}$ for some integer $n\geq1$, depending on circumstances.

The exponential functions you are considering are very special functions. In order to find the fundamental period of $f\cdot g$ when $f(t):=e^{2it}$ and $g(t)=e^{3it}$ we have to look at the situation in detail.

The function $t\mapsto e^{it}$ has fundamental period $2\pi$ (and not $=6T$, as you wrote). It follows that $f$ and $g$ have fundamental periods ${2\pi\over2}$ and ${2\pi\over3}$, whose lcm comes to $\ell=2\pi$ again. Now $f(t)\cdot g(t)=e^{5it}$, so that $f\cdot g$ has fundamental period ${2\pi\over5}={\ell\over5}$.

Answer (score 1):

for function to be periodic with period $k $

$f(t)=f(t+k)$

$e^{5it}=e^{5it}.e^{5ik}\implies e^{5ik}=1=e^{i2\pi}$

therefore $k= \dfrac{2\pi}{5}$